# Plotting Histograms in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am working with R and want to plot histograms for each name in the 'Name' column wrt to the 'Scores' in R. Any insights are helpful.

Dataset

| Name | Score |
| --- | --- |
| Anna | 40 |
| David | 30 |
| juli | 20 |
| Anna | 20 |
| David | 50 |
| juli | 40 |
| Anna | 20 |
| David | 20 |
| juli | 20 |

How can I plot histograms for anna, David, and Juli using R?

Comment: one suggestion just dput(df) so that one can easily use your data to do the plot or other stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar data-structure

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
  sex=factor(rep(c("F", "M"), each=200)),
  weight=round(c(rnorm(200, mean=55, sd=5), rnorm(200, mean=65, sd=5)))
  )
head(df)
```

The code to plot

```
library(ggplot2)
# Basic histogram
ggplot(df, aes(x=weight)) + geom_histogram()
# Change the width of bins
ggplot(df, aes(x=weight)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1)
# Change colors
p<-ggplot(df, aes(x=weight)) + 
  geom_histogram(color="black", fill="white")
p
```

Answer (score 2):

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Anna", "David", "juli", "Anna", "David", 
"juli", "Anna", "David", "juli"), Score = c("40", "30", "20", 
"20", "50", "40", "20", "20", "20")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Plot. Idea is to use `facet_wrap` to create a histogram for each unique category in the `Name` column.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Score)) + geom_histogram(stat = "count") + theme_bw() + 
  facet_wrap(~Name)
```

[image: plot]